# Failed authentication using JWT and Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

I am currently working on the authentication part of a web app. I use a MongoDB instance that runs in a docker container. The server-side web app uses Node.js and Express.js. Here I show how a user logs in:

```
app.post("/api/auth/signin", async (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  const userRequested = await db.collection("users").findOne({username:username});

  if (userRequested == null) {
    res.status(401).json({
      message: "Requested user does not exist",
    });
    res.json(username);
  } else if (username == null || password == null) {
    res.status(401).json({
      message: "Null username or password are not allowed",
    });
  } else {
    if (userRequested.password === password) {

      jwt.sign({ user: userRequested }, "secretkey", (err, token) => {
        res.redirect("/api/budget/whoami");
      });
    } else {
      res.status(401).send({
        message: "Wrong credentials",
      });
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see, when the user inserts the correct credentials, I redirect to `/api/budget/whoami`.

The API handles the request as follows:

```
app.get("/api/budget/whoami", (req, res, next) => {
    //res.json(req.headers["authorization"]);
    const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];

    if (typeof bearerHeader !== undefined) {
      const bearerToken = bearerHeader.split(" ")[1];
      req.token = bearerToken;
      next();
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(403);
      res.json(req.headers["authorization"])
    }
  },
  (req, res) => {
    jwt.verify(req.token, "secretkey", (err, authData) => {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(403);
      } else {
        res.status(201);
        res.json({ authData });
      }
    });
  }
);
```

I used a simple form to try this out:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ajax</title>
        <script src="assets/js/app.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="loginForm" action="/api/auth/signin" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            <input type="submit" value="login" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, even if I use the correct credentials, the response after the redirection is `403 Forbidden`. For the moment, I want the redirection page to send a JSON document with the user information. I do not understand the error, I would kindly appreciate an explanation in simple terms.

Thank you in advance for your patience.

EDIT: I changed `"undefined"` to `undefined` and used the same key for signing and verifying as suggested. Now after the credentials are sent, the redirection is not performed and the page is loading indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Your type check for valid authorization header is wrong it should be

```js
 if (typeof bearerHeader !== undefined) {
      const bearerToken = bearerHeader.split(" ")[1];
      req.token = bearerToken;
      next();
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(403);
      res.json(req.headers["authorization"])
    }
```

you have added quotes around undefined so its comparing w.r.t string instead of actually `undefined` data type.

Comment: I made your changes and even used the same string to sign and verify as @mhd anas suggested. Now the redirection is not performed at all as it is stuck after the credentials are sent

Comment: check the network tab under chrome tools... that you are getting any response from nodejs or not

Comment: if you are not getting any response meants there is an error on the nodejs code.. you need to add try catch and figure it out... in your code error handling is not there at all.

Comment: I dont know if it helps can you check if the headers is   res.json(req.headers["authorization"]) ||   res.json(req.headers["Authorization"])

Sometimes the "Authorization" can be Uppercase

Also check what is your response.headers to see if there are headers attached to it. 
Try it with Postman @EminentEmperorPenguin

Comment: I don't see any Authorization header checking with postman @malfoy

Comment: headers will be always lowercase